# Haskell :: Finding Min and Max for a set of Tuple

Tags: haskell

I've tried to find min and max for tuple. Here the code goes:

```
fFindMinMax :: (Ord a, Ord b, Ord c, Ord d) => [(a, b, c, d)] -> (Double,Double,Double,Double,Double,Double)
fFindMinMax [(_, x, y, z)] = (minimum x, maximum x, minimum y, maximum y, minimum z, maximum z)
```

And the errors come for maximum x, maximum y and maximum z.

> Couldnt match expected type t1 Double with actual type b.

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: You plan to conjure up your six Doubles out of what? And why six and not forty two?

Comment: It is a set of coordinates (id, x, y, z). Thus I would like to extract the min and max for each x, y and z and put it into a value of 6.

Comment: How should the compiler know it's a set of coordinates and not a set of, say, strings? It cannot read your mind. You use types to convey this information. What is the type of your coordinates value?

Comment: The type for the coordinates is (Int, Double, Double, Double)

Comment: So use it to define your function.

Comment: Another problem of your definition is that your function will only ever work with a list with exactly one element (this is what `[(_, x, y, z)]` matches). So you need to change that.

Comment: Tried and errors "Couldnt match expected type  t0 double with actual type double". It happened at all minimum x, maximum x, minimum y, ......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First attempt

First of all, your current pattern:

```
fFindMinMax [(_, x, y, z)] = ...
```

means that it will only work if you pass a list with *one* element. So from the moment you pass an empty list, or a list with two or more elements, this will fail.

What you need is a `map` to obtain all the second/third/fourth elements of the tuples. We can do this with:

```
fFindMinMax cs = ...
    where cSnd = map (\(_,x,_,_) -> x) cs
          cThr = map (\(_,_,y,_) -> y) cs
          cFou = map (\(_,_,_,z) -> z) cs
```

So now the question is: *what* should we write as function predicate. You actually already made an attempt there that works: we can calculate the `minimum cSnd` and `maximum cSnd` and so on for every coordinate. So:

```
fFindMinMax cs = (minimum cSnd, maximum cSnd, minimum cThr, maximum cThr, minimum cFou, maximum cFou)
    where cSnd = map (\(_,x,_,_) -> x) cs
          cThr = map (\(_,_,y,_) -> y) cs
          cFou = map (\(_,_,_,z) -> z) cs
```

Now what is the type of the function? We do not have to restrict us to `Double`, nor do we have to make sure that all coordinates have the same type, the type signature of `fFindMinMax` can be:

```
fFindMinMax :: (Ord x, Ord y, Ord z) => [(a, x, y, z)] -> (x, x, y, y, z, z)
fFindMinMax cs = (minimum cSnd, maximum cSnd, minimum cThr, maximum cThr, minimum cFou, maximum cFou)
    where cSnd = map (\(_,x,_,_) -> x) cs
          cThr = map (\(_,_,y,_) -> y) cs
          cFou = map (\(_,_,_,z) -> z) cs
```

Note that this program will error if you give it an empty list, since the `minimum` or `maximum` of an empty list is not defined.

## Improve memory consumption

A problem with the above solution is that we construct lists with the second, third and fourth element. Since we do not calculate the minimum and maximum at the same time, this means that we will end up storing this lists into memory.

We can improve the code by writing a helper function that calculates the `minimum` and the `maximum` concurrently for the same list:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

minmax :: Ord a => [a] -> (a,a)
minmax [] = error "Empty list"
minmax (h:t) = minmax' h h t
    where minmax' a b [] = (a,b)
          minmax' !a !b (c:cs) = minmax' (min a c) (max b c) cs
```

How does this function works? Well the first line is rather straightforward: in case we are given an empty list, we can not calculate the minimum or the maximum, so we raise an error *Empty list*. In the latter case that list has a first item `h` and the rest of the items `t`. We consider `h` to be the thus far obtained minimum and maximum: if a list contains a single element, then that element is both the minimum and the maximum of that list. So we call an extra function `minmax' :: Ord a => a -> a -> [a] -> a` that calculates the minimum and maximum by giving it the minimum and maximum obtained thus far (`h` and `h`) and the remaining of the list.

Each iteration, it will take the next element `c` and calculate the minimum by calculated `min` with the thus far minimum `a` and the next element `c`, and calculate the maximum with the thus far maximum `b` and the next element `c`. We keep iterative doing this until we reach the end of the list. In that case the thus far obtained minimum and maximum are the final minimum and maximum. So we can return them as `(a,b)`.

Then we can use the function like:

```
fFindMinMax :: (Ord x, Ord y, Ord z) => [(a, x, y, z)] -> (x, x, y, y, z, z)
fFindMinMax cs = (xmi, xma, ymi, yma, zmi, zma)
    where (xmi, xma) = minmax $ map (\(_,x,_,_) -> x) cs
          (ymi, yma) = minmax $ map (\(_,_,y,_) -> y) cs
          (zmi, zma) = minmax $ map (\(_,_,_,z) -> z) cs
```

Comment: Yes!! This is it. I like the way you explaining it. Steps shown according to the flow. Thanks!!!

Comment: It's worth to say that this task can be solved for the constant memory space (in contrast to this).

Comment: Can you elaborate (like you did previously) on how you define function minmax? Its hard for me to digest it. Sorry.

I've tried to compile it but errors with max b h.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I got this message, Illegal bang-pattern (use bang patterns) : ! a. Did I missed some setting?

Comment: @SirDK: did you add the `{-# LANGUAGE ... #-} part at the top of the file?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem When I did that, it goes back to the previous error: the function max is applied to two arguments, but its type Int has none.

Comment: @SirDK: I tested it locally. What happens if you use an empty file and put the last two code fragments in it?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried to create new file and build it in Leksah, but the error still there. I'm not sure why and wondering. I'm pretty sure that using min and max is better than maximum and minimum for large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

## Constant space solution

```
fFindMinMax :: (Ord x, Ord y, Ord z) => [(a, x, y, z)] -> (x, x, y, y, z, z)
fFindMinMax ((_, x, y, z):rest) = foldl' minmax (x, x, y, y, z, z) rest
fFindMinMax []                  = error "fFindMinMax: empty list"
  where
    (xMin', xMax', yMin', yMax', zMin', zMax') `minmax` (_, x, y, z) =
        let
          !xMin = min xMin' x
          !xMax = max xMax' x
          !yMin = min yMin' y
          !yMax = max yMax' y
          !zMin = min zMin' z
          !zMax = max zMax' z
        in (xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, zMin, zMax)
```